# Map returns Object instead of being deduced through succeeding calls

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I'm playing with Java 8 and e(fx)clipse and just trying things out. I'm trying to apply a map function that removes all a's from a nullable string. However, the succeeding filter functions are having compile errors because map is returning `Optional<Object>` instead of `Optional<String>`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Optional.ofNullable(string)
    .map( s -> s.replaceAll("a", "") )
    .filter( s -> !((String) s).isEmpty() ) //notice the need for cast
    .map( s -> "String: " + s )
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with type inferencing. [`Optional.map`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map%28java.util.function.Function%29) takes an argument of type [`Function<? super T, ? extend U>`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) and returns an `Optional<U>`.

Now for `String`, the type `T` is being inferred as `String`, and `U` is being inferred as `Object`, that is why it returns an `Optional<Object>`. I've not used Java 8 too much, but I guess this is what is happening.

You can get `Optional<String>` by giving an explicit type argument:

```
Optional.ofNullable(string).<String>map(s -> s.replaceAll("a", ""))
    .filter(s -> s.isEmpty())
    .map(s -> "String" + s)
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

`<String>` in between `.` and `map(...)` denotes an explicit type argument, to ensure that the type argument `U` is inferred as `String`.

Frankly I would have expected that to work without explicit type argument, because the `Function` that is passed to `map` has both the input and output type as `String`:

```
s (type is String) -> s.replaceAll(..) (this also returns String)
```

and since, `String` satisfies both the bounds - `? extends T` and `? super U`. Remember in generics, `String super String` and `String extends String` are `true`. So, it took me  by surprise why it isn't working as expected. But again, for these kinds of surprises only I guess, Java has got *explicit type argument*.

**Note:** So it turned out to be an issue with eclipse. The original code works fine on command line.

---

Another option is to create a `Function<T, R>` object beforehand, and pass it:

```
Function<String, String> func = s -> s.replaceAll("a", "");

Optional.ofNullable(string).map(func)
    .filter(s -> s.isEmpty())
    .map(s -> "String" + s)
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

**Reference:**

- [What is explicit type argument inference?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20explicit%20type%20argument%20specification?)

Comment: Will Java ever get Generics right? Sigh... and now with lambdas we'll need type inference more than ever.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Well, I'm too surprised with the failure of type inference here. I expected it to work fine. For `? extends T, ? super U`, the types could have been inferred as `String,` given that the function we pass - `s -> s.replaceAll`, both have type `String`. Seems to be some bug moving around in Java 8 type inference, but I cannot be sure.

Comment: That's the pain with type inference, you can't debug it. Reading the specs will help very little. Scala has similar problems, though, and it has much more sophisticated type inference. Basically, it does what you mean... until it doesn't, at some random point, for unfathomable reasons. You're not supposed to ask why, just slavishly insert an explicit type tag and move on.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Exactly. How type inference works in different cases is hard to find out. And sadly, there is always an option. So, no one bothers to look into the problem of implicit type inference.

Comment: I went in to try OP's code out, and behold, it works for me! No errors.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Seems like the issue with damn Eclipse, which still hasn't been completely updated for Java 8

Comment: Ah, so it's Eclipse's compiler error? I haven't even seen an Eclipse which works with Java 8, which is it?

Comment: I'm using e(fx)clipse :)

Comment: @Chad e(fx)clipse is an extension of the basic Eclipse IDE, so I wondered what version of the basic IDE supports Java 8. Does the Kepler release already support it? I thought no final release supported it yet.

Comment: Kepler doesn't support Java 8 yet. Adding <String> before map did work however. It seems it is indeed an eclipse error. I have tried it with Intellij and it worked.

Comment: @RohitJain Is it possible for you to post the issue regarding eclipse as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I downloaded an eclipse, I don't remember which one is it. Certainly not the `(fx)` one. But that's eclipse issue for sure.

Comment: I'm using eclipse Luna.

Comment: @Chad Added that part in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your problem has already been fixed in a later Java 8 build because this compiles for me without errors:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Optional.ofNullable("x")
            .map(s -> s.replaceAll("a","b"))
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty());
}
```

My Java version:

```
$ java -version

java version "1.8.0-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-ea-b108)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b50, mixed mode)
```

Note that the Java JDK build number is irrelevant if you are seeing errors within Eclipse because Eclipse uses its own Java compiler. Try to compile your classes with `javac` from the command line.

Comment: I'm using build 1.8.0-ea-b109, build 25.0-b51, mixed mode. Something might have changed through the builds. Thanks for this information.

Comment: Note that the Java JDK build number is irrelevant if you are seeing errors within Eclipse because Eclipse uses its own Java compiler. Try to compile your classes with `javac` from the command line.

Comment: It seems it is indeed an eclipse error. I have tried it with Intellij and it worked.